# How to decode "binary" encoded string into raw binary Buffer?

Tags: node.js, encoding, binary, imagemagick, buffer

The [NodeJS docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) stress that the `binary` string encoding is heavily discouraged since it will be dropped at some point in the future.

However, I'm trying to generate image thumbnails with the [`node-imagemagick`](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) module, which can only output `binary` encoded strings.

My end goal is to submit the generated thumbnail as a BLOB into a SQLite3 database (I'm using [`node-sqlite3`](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3)), so I figured I need the thumbnail as a binary Buffer object.

How do I directly decode the `binary` encoded output from `node-imagemagick` into a raw binary Buffer (not just a Buffer that contains a `binary` encoded string)? I'm not keen on using `base64`...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```js
const buffer = new Buffer(binaryString, "binary");
```

Tested with:

```sh
$ node
> var binaryString = "\xff\xfa\xc3\x4e";
> var buffer = new Buffer(binaryString, "binary");
> console.log(buffer);
<Buffer ff fa c3 4e>
```

**Update**: since v10.0.0 - Use `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])` instead.

Comment: You didn't misinterpreted the docs. They clearly state that "binary" encoding will get removed! I'm also running against the same problem while capturing output from ImageMagick to store into MongoDB. "binary" is the only encoding that seems to work to get STDOUT in the database correctly. So what is the alternative?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit raise an issue with the library author on github to update their module to use buffers... it will surely get resolved before `"binary"` gets removed from node?

Comment: The update could have indicated what encoding to use for the binary data, otherwise this is just as useless as the docs

Answer (score 2):

```
const bin = 'PK\u0003\u0004\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0013{yB½g].9\u0001\u0000\u00005\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\u0000\u0000[Content_Types].xml'
const buf = new Buffer.from(bin, 'binary');
console.log(buf)
// <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 08 00 13 7b 79 42 bd 67 5d 2e 39 01 00 00 35 04 00 00 13 00 00 00 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73 5d 2e 78 6d 6c>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use node's Buffer for encoding.

You can try `iconv-lite` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) should this ever start to fail:

```
var encode = require("iconv-lite");
var binaryString = "\xff\xfa\xc3\x4e";
var buffer = encode(binaryString, "binary");
console.log(buffer);
// Prints <Buffer ff fa c3 4e>
```

**UPDATE**
The `iconv-lite` library has switched to es6 syntax now. So following code won't work. You have to do something like:

```
import { encode } from "iconv-lite";
```

Not gonna update my code as this will constantly change. Consult documentation:
https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite